# Converting an IIFE to module.exports (and use Webpack)

Tags: javascript, webpack, iife

I want to start using Webpack.

Currently, in one project I have the next lines:

```
<script defer src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.js"></script>
<script defer src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="/js/doubletaptogo.js"></script>
<script defer src="/js/init.js"></script>
```

I guess the following:

- I should not download `modernizr` neither `jquery` because both are downloaded from their respective CDNs.
- `DoubleTapToGo` is also a library and it is a minified local file. It is expressed via an `immediately invoked function expression`. So I should convert it into a `module` using `module.exports`, but I don't know how to do that and if I really should:
- `init.js` should require `DoubleTapToGo` as a module, to produce just one file and finally have 2 libraries and 1 local JS file.

Please correct me.
Thank you in advance.

---

**doubletaptogo.js has the following content:**

```
;(function($,window,document,undefined){$.fn.doubleTapToGo=function(params){if(!('ontouchstart'in window)&&!navigator.msMaxTouchPoints&&!navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/windows phone os 7/i))return false;this.each(function(){var curItem=false;$(this).on('click',function(e){var item=$(this);if(item[0]!=curItem[0]){e.preventDefault();curItem=item;}});$(document).on('click touchstart MSPointerDown',function(e){var resetItem=true,parents=$(e.target).parents();for(var i=0;i<parents.length;i++)if(parents[i]==curItem[0])resetItem=false;if(resetItem)curItem=false;});});return this;};})(jQuery,window,document);
```